Where can I find the minimum math needed for General Relativity?
The knowledge that I already have is linear algebra, ordinary co-ordinate geometry, some vectors, calculus up to basic differential equations, and Special Relativity. Where can I learn the minimum math necessary for understanding General Relativity? I am aiming at an understanding that is neither too ambitious nor superficial, but gives  a clear grasp of the LOGICAL structure in which each step in reasoning compels the next one, rather than  leaving matters to Einstein's intuition at a crucial point. Intuition, trial and error, etc. certainly play a huge part in the journey of discovery (heuristics) but, having completed the journey, it must surely be possible to look  back and trace out a clear logical path leading to the final truth.
Any help in this would be most gratefully appreciated.

Most textbooks present it logically. What are you complaining about? You'll need tensors and their derivatives, which the textbooks would cover. You can already start on some of the simpler textbooks on the topic.

Here's a nice GR intro / overview that you can follow with your existing mathematical skills: https://hepweb.ucsd.edu/ph110b/110b_notes/node72.html For more, see https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/gr/gr.html

Thanks. But the first link leads to a warning that the connection is not private and potentially poses a risk to my personal details. Any advice?

Sorry. That site is perfectly safe. It's the University of California, San Diego. But their certificate expired 3 days ago.

For GR, even Gravitation is fairly self-contained (just some basic differential calculus is required). That’s generally the de facto source for many simpler equations/information/references in many papers, too.

I learnt general relativity by reading the book "General Relativity, the theoretical minimum" by Leonard Sussland. This book is self-contained. I read the book from cover to cover without any need to consult other mathematics or physics book. A good starting point for your adventure.
